# What's the best way to populate foreign keys using a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I need to import a big csv file into a Rails project. I'm using:
ruby 2.1.2p95
Rails 4.1.1
mysql  Ver 14.14

I'm trying to do this as a rake task, by first creating records in the independent tables, get the record id's for those records, and use these for the foreign keys to populate records in the dependent tables.

I'm trying to create just the independent records, and print out these foreign id's, operating on a small test file first.

However, I'm getting this end-of-file I don't understand:

> ```
> rake aborted!
> SyntaxError: /Users/rickcasey/Projects/Programming/WikiFrac/wfrails/lib/tasks/import_partial.rake:94:
> ```
>
> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

This is what my rake script looks like:

```
#lib/tasks/import_partial.rake
require 'csv'

# Independent tables:
#  Companies
#  Counties
#  Fields
#  Formations
#  Gastypes
#  Wells
#  
# Dependendecies and foreign key field used to find correct record id:
#  Facilities.company_id -> Companies.company_name
#  Facilities.field_id   -> Fields.field_name
#  Facilities.county_id  -> Counties.county_name
#  Wells.gastype_id      -> GasTypes.gas_type

task :import_partial => :environment do    
    csv.foreach('public/partial.csv', :headers => true) do |row|

            # create records in independent tables

            # create the Company object
            this_company_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[county_name])
            if !(Company.exists?(company_name: this_company_name))
              Companies.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[company_name operator_num]))
            end
            thecompany = Company.find(this_company_name)
            company_id = thecompany.id

            # create the County object
            this_county_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[county])
            if !(County.exists?(county_name: this_county_name))
              Counties.create(county_name: this_county_name)
            end
            thecounty = County.find(this_county_name)
            county_id = thecounty.id

            # create the GasType object  
            this_gastype_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[gas_type])
            if !(GasType.exists?(gastype_name: this_gastype_name))
              GasType.create(gastype_name: this_gastype_name)
            end
            thegastype = GasType.find(this_gastype_name)
            gastype_id = thegastype.id


            # create the Field object
            this_field_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[field])
            if !(Field.exists?(field_name: this_field_name))
              Field.create(field_name: this_field_name, field_code: field_code)
            end
            thefield = Field.find(this_field_name)
            field_id = thefield.id

            # create the Formations object  
            this_formation_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[formation])
            if !(Formation.exists?(formation_name: this_formation_name))
              Counties.create(formation: this_formation_name, formation_code: formation_code)
            end
            theformation = Formation.find(this_formation_name)
            formation_id = theformation.id

            # debugging:
            puts "company_id:", company_id
            puts "county_id:", county_id
            puts "gastype_id:", gastype_id
            puts "field_id:", field_id

            # create records in dependent tables:
            # Use the record id's from above independent table create records containing foreign keys:

            #Facilities.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[dir_e_w dir_n_s dist_e_w dist_n_s facility_name facility_num ground_elev lat long meridian qtrqtr range sec twp utm_x utm_y])

            #Wells.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[api_county_code api_seq_num first_prod_date form_status_date formation_status sidetrack_num spud_date status_date td_date test_date wbmeasdepth wbtvd well_bore_status well_name])


        end
    end
end
```

Any suggestions much appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 1 too many `end` statements at the end of your file.